# Plans to support .NET Core in Bot Framework SDK?

Tags: .net-core, botframework, azure-bot-service

Is there any plan to support .NET Core in the near future? I mean, without refactoring my bot code. There are still components not compatible with it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is planned and in the works.  You can follow the topic on this related GitHub issue: [[Feature Request] Porting to .NET core #572](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/572)

**Update 2017-10-26:**
Bot Framework team is working on a complete rewrite of BotBuilder SDK (v4) which will be fully compatible with .NET Core.

**Update 2017-12-14**
Bot Builder v3 - [New Bot Connector support for ASP.NET Core 2.0 and 1.1 has been released on NuGet!](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/11/28/new-bot-connector-support-net-core-2-0/)

> We’ve released two new nuget packages for the Microsoft Bot Connector to support .NET Core 2.0:
>
> - [Microsoft.Bot.Connector.AspNetCore.1.1.3.2.nupkg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.AspNetCore/1.1.3.2)
> - [Microsoft.Bot.Connector.AspNetCore.2.0.0.3.nupkg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.AspNetCore/)
>
> The above packages each target ASPNetCore 1.x and ASPNetCore 2.x respectively, and provision authentication for your bot. They must also use Microsoft.Bot.Connector.3.12.2.4 or higher.